# "victim to" or "victim of"

Tags: prepositions

I know that if you fall victim to something or someone, you suffer as a result of them, or you are killed by them. But this rule is also not followed hard and fast, like in the sentence given below:

> You either take what you want or become a victim **to** someone else who
>   will.

So I would like someone to clarify in which context to use  "to" and "for" with the word "victim".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fall victim to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fall-victim-to) is a complete idiom in English and is generally used with diseases, disasters, and other catastrophic situations. Otherwise, use **victim of**.

> In the 14th century, about half of Europe's population *fell victim to* the plague.
>
> Don't click on unknown links in your email or you might *fall victim to* a phishing scheme.
>
> Mary is the latest *victim of* the pickpocket.
>
> Don't become a *victim of* habit.